# Getting ValueError: unknown url type: ' '

Tags: python, python-requests, musixmatch

I have this code below that iterate through some tracks. And then for each track I want to  use the musixmatch api to get and print the lyrics of the track based  on the artist name and track name.

**code that iterete trough some tracks and print the lyrics:**

```
for i, v in tracks.items():
    artist = tracks[i]['artist'].replace(" ", "+")
    title = tracks[i]['title'].replace(" ", "+")

    print(tracks)

    print(song_lyric(title, artist))
```

**The print(tracks) returns in this format:**

```
{12: {'trackID': 12, 'title': 'Achtung Baby', 'number': '1', 'artist': 'U2', 'album': 'Achtung Baby', 'albumID': 2, 'duration': '291'}
```

**When the code exuted the lyrics for the firsts tracks are printed, but then it appears an error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ozzy/PycharmProjects/getData/getData.py", line 239, in <module>
    print(song_lyric(title, artist))
  File "C:/Users/Ozzy/PycharmProjects/getData/getData.py", line 72, in song_lyric
    lyrics_tracking(tracking_url)
  File "C:/Users/Ozzy/PycharmProjects/getData/getData.py", line 79, in lyrics_tracking
    request = urllib.request.Request(querystring)
  File "C:\Users\Ozzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "C:\Users\Ozzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 355, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Users\Ozzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 384, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: ''
```

Do you know why this error is appearing?

The methods to get the lyrics from musixmatch are public available:

```
def song_lyric(song_name, artist_name):
    while True:
        querystring = apiurl_musixmatch + "matcher.lyrics.get?q_track=" + urllib.parse.quote(
            song_name) + "&q_artist=" + urllib.parse.quote(
            artist_name) + "&apikey=" + apikey_musixmatch + "&format=json&f_has_lyrics=1"
        # matcher.lyrics.get?q_track=sexy%20and%20i%20know%20it&q_artist=lmfao
        request = urllib.request.Request(querystring)
        # request.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + client_access_token)
        request.add_header("User-Agent",
                           "curl/7.9.8 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl 7.9.8 (OpenSSL 0.9.6b) (ipv6 enabled)")  # Must include user agent of some sort, otherwise 403 returned
        while True:
            try:
                response = urllib.request.urlopen(request,
                                                  timeout=4)  # timeout set to 4 seconds; automatically retries if times out
                raw = response.read()
            except socket.timeout:
                print("Timeout raised and caught")
                continue
            break
        json_obj = json.loads(raw.decode('utf-8'))
        body = json_obj["message"]["body"]["lyrics"]["lyrics_body"]
        copyright = json_obj["message"]["body"]["lyrics"]["lyrics_copyright"]
        tracking_url = json_obj["message"]["body"]["lyrics"]["html_tracking_url"]
        #print(tracking_url)
        lyrics_tracking(tracking_url)
        return (body + "\n\n" + copyright)


def lyrics_tracking(tracking_url):
    while True:
        querystring = tracking_url
        request = urllib.request.Request(querystring)
        # request.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + client_access_token)
        request.add_header("User-Agent",
                           "curl/7.9.8 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl 7.9.8 (OpenSSL 0.9.6b) (ipv6 enabled)")  # Must include user agent of some sort, otherwise 403 returned
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(request,
                                              timeout=4)  # timeout set to 4 seconds; automatically retries if times out
            raw = response.read()
        except socket.timeout:
            print("Timeout raised and caught")
            continue
        break
        print(raw)
```

**Full working exemple that reproduces the error:**

```
import requests
import json
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import socket

apikey_musixmatch = '0b4a363bbd71974c2634837d5b5d1d9a' #generated for the example
apiurl_musixmatch = 'http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/'

api_key = "b088cbedecd40b35dd89e90f55227ac2" #generated for the example
def song_lyric(song_name, artist_name):
    while True:
        querystring = apiurl_musixmatch + "matcher.lyrics.get?q_track=" + urllib.parse.quote(
            song_name) + "&q_artist=" + urllib.parse.quote(
            artist_name) + "&apikey=" + apikey_musixmatch + "&format=json&f_has_lyrics=1"
        # matcher.lyrics.get?q_track=sexy%20and%20i%20know%20it&q_artist=lmfao
        request = urllib.request.Request(querystring)
        # request.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + client_access_token)
        request.add_header("User-Agent",
                           "curl/7.9.8 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl 7.9.8 (OpenSSL 0.9.6b) (ipv6 enabled)")  # Must include user agent of some sort, otherwise 403 returned
        while True:
            try:
                response = urllib.request.urlopen(request,
                                                  timeout=4)  # timeout set to 4 seconds; automatically retries if times out
                raw = response.read()
            except socket.timeout:
                print("Timeout raised and caught")
                continue
            break
        json_obj = json.loads(raw.decode('utf-8'))
        body = json_obj["message"]["body"]["lyrics"]["lyrics_body"]
        copyright = json_obj["message"]["body"]["lyrics"]["lyrics_copyright"]
        tracking_url = json_obj["message"]["body"]["lyrics"]["html_tracking_url"]
        print("Tracking_url====================" +tracking_url + "==================================")
        lyrics_tracking(tracking_url)
        return (body + "\n\n" + copyright)


def lyrics_tracking(tracking_url):
    while True:
        querystring = tracking_url
        request = urllib.request.Request(querystring)
        # request.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + client_access_token)
        request.add_header("User-Agent",
                           "curl/7.9.8 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl 7.9.8 (OpenSSL 0.9.6b) (ipv6 enabled)")  # Must include user agent of some sort, otherwise 403 returned
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(request,
                                              timeout=4)  # timeout set to 4 seconds; automatically retries if times out
            raw = response.read()
        except socket.timeout:
            print("Timeout raised and caught")
            continue
        break
        print(raw)

ID = 0

#get top artists from country
artists = {}
for i in range(2, 3):
    artists_response = requests.get(
        'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&format=json&page=' + str(i) + '&api_key=' + api_key)
    artists_data = artists_response.json()
    for artist in artists_data["topartists"]["artist"]:


        name = artist["name"]
        url = artist["url"]
        if ID > 1: continue
        artists[ID] = {}
        artists[ID]['ID'] = ID
        artists[ID]['name'] = name
        ID += 1

    for i, v in artists.items():
        chosen = artists[i]['name'].replace(" ", "+")
        artist_response = requests.get(
            'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&format=json&artist=' + chosen + '&api_key=' + api_key)
        artist_data = artist_response.json()


# get top albums of the artists
albums = {}
for i, v in artists.items():
    chosen = artists[i]['name'].replace(" ", "+")
    topalbums_response = requests.get(
        'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&format=json&artist=' + chosen + '&api_key=' + api_key + '&limit=5')
    albums_data = topalbums_response.json()

    for album in albums_data['topalbums']['album']:
        name = album["name"]
        url = album["url"]

        albums[ID] = {}
        albums[ID]['ID'] = ID
        albums[ID]['artist'] = artists[i]['name']
        albums[ID]['artistID'] = artists[i]['ID']
        albums[ID]['name'] = name

        ID += 1

# Get tracks of the album

tracks = {}
for i, v in albums.items():
    artist = albums[i]['artist'].replace(" ", "+")
    name = albums[i]['name'].replace(" ", "+")
    album_response_data = requests.get(
        'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&format=json&api_key=' + api_key + '&artist=' + artist + '&album=' + name)
    album_response = album_response_data.json()



    for album in album_response['album']['tracks']['track']:
        title = album['name']
        tracks[ID] = {}
        tracks[ID]['trackID'] = ID
        tracks[ID]['title'] = title
        tracks[ID]['artist'] = albums[i]['artist']
        tracks[ID]['album'] = albums[i]['name']
        tracks[ID]['albumID'] = albums[i]['ID']

        ID += 1

for i, v in tracks.items():
    artist = tracks[i]['artist'].replace(" ", "+")
    title = tracks[i]['title'].replace(" ", "+")

    # print the lyric of each track
    print(song_lyric(title, artist))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like url is not correct. It happens here:

`tracking_url = json_obj["message"]["body"]["lyrics"]["html_tracking_url"]`

If you have ability to run that API locally and see what is returned into `tracking_url`, you can find out what is still wrong with it.

#### UPDATE:

I reproduced it, so the `urllib.request` cannot process empty string URL: `""`, that is why you need to check if the `tracking_url != ""` and only if its not empty string or None you need to request for the song.

Comment: Thanks. tracking_url returns on this thisformat: https://tracking.musixmatch.com/t1.0/m_html/e_1/sn_0/l_14384718/su_0/tr_3vUCADZICo12C1YPe1cDRTbSP_UfG83RheUujKiwj8DxarsTJcG3vlyobXSKDp6EcwHmTWVqzOM8x-EjaVgBPDr5Ia6fM3jPMZbVWKTJq0sIRjmCNuyZSjC34WVIPnhSw9tjUpmT-MoMx222Wq5AEKkLLDYpuMR9o6Zy8oQI47hNeXA_9Ea-76XhjyEaBCMm8cjlG71sQYeW3h5fJH28ZwsOolsW8W-UYsJxqHb5Ej1N2BDGRvVKQjrBs7mzaUBypEuNLPmsv01ib6851l15WC99IaLjcLjh3D8u1fYuSNWk-J5iEXGyE3EIUC3wx02ElBoKo2VZapJ_U5lVxxEr8v6gqmFcpFiov8wXkh8IoDnbi3IuXjpZdhTLMU_WJkWrYUmA4hY7TydgP9afQM4Lk0sMHMrQfxYHMZkmAYFaui6sTQNJfnBAvta6tNG5WoiZJXyE5GzkYNT95VE6bJH4/

Comment: In the song that it gets the error tracking_url dont print nothing.